# How to run returned php script after decryption of encrypted php script (developing an encryption/decryption tool for protecting php codes)

Tags: php, c, linux, encryption

I want to protect my php codes on my web server. So I develop an encryption/decryption application using C. I encrypt all my php files successfully during the process shows below:

php Source Code(php file) --> Encoder Tool --> Encrypted Code

Then, I developed a php extension named "MyDecrptionFunc" which gets an encrypted code and will decrypt it and return the decryption.But I don't know how to run the returned php script. I used eval function like below code and it worked:

```
<?php eval(MyDecrptionFunc("Encrypted Code")); ?>
```

But I don't want to use the eval function. I want the php script runs as I call the php extension like below code:

```
<?php MyDecrptionFunc("Encrypted Code"); ?>
```

So, I think that I have to run the decrypted code from my php extension written in c, but I don't know how to do that.

PS:
 All my developing is in Linux environment. 
The source php file contains also html, java script and css. 
The php scripts are in relation with database.

Comment: Not related to your question, but why do you want to protect your PHP on the web server?

Comment: The PHP code is not sent by the web-server to the clients, unless you made some mistake. The code is already evaluated on the server, and the resulting HTML code is sent to the client without any PHP code visible.

Comment: I have to install the web application on customer's server and I don't want they have access to the source code.

Comment: How are you providing the encryption key? If there isn't a key, there's no security. If there is one and it's stored on the server, there's no security. Unless you're passing it securely from the client on every request, you're likely not buying yourself anything and just slowing everything down, if it works at all.

Comment: We use a hardware token. We give One token for each server and the key is stored on token.

Comment: What I want to do, is like protecting the server side source code with software like phpshadow or ionCube PHP Encoder. If this protecting is completely useless, so what are these commercial software for?

Answer (score 0):

You probably can change your http server setup: replace the php handler to call your decoder (or a script around that). The server will specify the original request in the environment, thus the called script/decrypt application knows which php file to decrypt and run by piping it through a php interpreter. You forward the output of the executed php file to the web server (via its socket).

Slow but probably working.

My personal experience in 15 years of software business in a proprietary environment: encrypting php files to protect intellectual property is unnecessary, annoying and error prone. Don't do it, you won't really gain anything.